# Custom TableViewCell With Image Disappearing When Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have created a custom tableviewcell class and the cells load perfectly, however, when I click on them they disappear and come back when I click on a different cell. Can anyone help me understand why? Thanks in advance!

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell
UIView *backgroundView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65)];
    UIView *visibleBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29, 0, backgroundView.bounds.size.width -58, backgroundView.bounds.size.height)];
    [visibleBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewCell.png"]]];
    [backgroundView addSubview:visibleBackgroundView];
    self.backgroundView = backgroundView;



}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
if (selected) {
    UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65)];
    UIView *visibleSelectedBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29, 0, backgroundView.bounds.size.width -58, backgroundView.bounds.size.height)];
    [visibleSelectedBackground setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedTableViewCell@2x.png"]]];
    [selectedBackgroundView addSubview:visibleSelectedBackground];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
}
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated{
[super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
if (highlighted) {
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
}
}
```

Comment: Can you set the highlight to yes and see what happens?

Comment: If I set highlight to yes, it turns the cell blue for a short time before it disappears.

Comment: Have you checked to see if [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedTableViewCell@2x.png"] returns anything?

Comment: It should be `selectedTableViewCell.png` but yes they both returned images. Thanks for catching that though

Comment: I looked at this a little more, and it sure seems like a bug to me. I tried the same code on a UICollectionViewCell, and it worked there. You can give the selectedBackgroundView a background color, and that shows up, but adding a subview to it doesn't seem to work. The cells don't disappear, by the way. If you set the highlighted text color for the cell's textLabel to something other than white, you will see that it's still there when selected (the normal behavior is to turn the text white on selection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the following solution

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell{
    UIView *backgroundView;
    UIView *visibleBackgroundView;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65)];
    visibleBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29, 0, backgroundView.bounds.size.width -58, backgroundView.bounds.size.height)];
    [visibleBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewCell.png"]]];
    [backgroundView addSubview:visibleBackgroundView];
    self.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
if (selected) {

}
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated{
[super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
if (highlighted) {
    [visibleBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedTableViewCell.png"]]];
} else{
     [visibleBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewCell.png"]]];
}
}
```